# How to create custom graphs in Ganglia?

Tags: ganglia

How can I create custom graphs in ganglia.  I have couple of scripts written, which can return the data in intergers, I want to graph them in ganglia. I can get the output from my scripts every minute.

Comment: gmetric:https://github.com/ganglia/gmetric